# Ubuntu 16.04 and Quadro M2000M

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia, graphics

I have a Fujitsu Celsius H760 with a Quadro M2000M.

I tried different ways to install the nVidia-driver because I need CUDA support (for my studies).

The main problem is that after the installation process I get the following error-message (reboot):

```
bbswitch: No discrete VGA device found
```

It is not possible to restart the computer again. I searched for a long time on the internet, but I can't find an answer.

I've added the following ppa for installation of `nvidia-375`:
At least i used the following ppa to install the nvidia-375 package:

- `ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa`
- `https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers`

Do you know a work-around?

Comment: Is it a UEFI based laptop? Did you disable Secure Boot in BIOS?

Comment: If i type  [ -d /sys/firmware/efi ] && echo "EFI boot on HDD" || echo "Legacy boot on HDD" then i receive "EFI boot on HDD" so i guess yes :-). I never changed the settings in the BIOS. Should i chage them to Secure Boot in BIOS? Sorry i am new to stackexchange. next time i try to make it look like code.

Comment: Secure Boot is disabled / Protected Signatures is enabled (User Mode) / Customized Signatures is disabled (Standard).

Comment: You have some advanced bios. Try to disable Protected signatures. And also when the system does not boot into GUI, go to console by Ctrl+Alt+F1 and try `sudo modprobe nvidia` to see if it loads or not.

Comment: I disabled Secure Boot in Bios. "modprobe nvidia" shows no results either an error message or something else. The system still doesnt boot.

Comment: I give up then. No more ideas. Sry.

Comment: Hmmm...ok. Thank you. Is it normal that if i type "lspci | grep 'VGA'" into the console that ubuntu only detects Intel Skylake Integrated Graphics? I think there should be nvidia too?

Comment: `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'`

Comment: "00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Skylake Integrated Graphics...." and "3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM107GL [Quadro M2000M] (rev a2)...Kernel driver in use: nvidia" - i dont know what this means. Are they both activated?

Comment: I found following information in /var/log/gpu-manager.log . "Is nvidia blacklisted? yes"

Comment: '/var/log/kernel.log' says that "nvidia: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel". I think its related to Secure Boot? But i disabled it...hmm... maybe i should sign the driver..